# 'svn import' returns E175003: The PROPFIND response did not include the requested version-controlled-configuration value

Tags: apache, svn, https, webserver

Currently we are upgrading our development platform to the most recent packages in Gentoo Prefix. This involves the SVN command line client to be upgraded from svn-1.6.9 to svn-1.8.10. The server side should not be changed, except it is mandatory (svn-1.6.9 with DAV on Apache-2.2.15 - https).

After some pain with scripts, now everything is working with svn-1.8.10 except `svn import`.

Whenever I fire

```
svn import . https://svn.sources.XXXXXXXX.at/Mactest -F svn-commit.tmp
```

I get the error

> svn: E175003: The PROPFIND response did not include the requested version-controlled-configuration value

I tried to get a PROPFIND response for the "requested version-controlled-configuration" with curl:

```
curl -si -u user:pass -k https://svn.sources.XXXXXX.at/ -H "Depth: 0" --request PROPFIND  -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <propfind xmlns="DAV:"> <prop> <version-controlled-configuration xmlns="DAV:"/> </prop> </propfind>'
```

The response on this request looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:26:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 SVN/1.6.9
Content-Length: 414
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
<D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp3="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/">
<D:href>/</D:href>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<lp1:version-controlled-configuration><D:href>/!svn/vcc/default</D:href></lp1:version-controlled-configuration>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

What's wrong here? Has anyone succeed in doing an `svn import` with a more recent client than installed on the SVN server side?
Maybe something is wrong in the Apache configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It was solved by calling mkdir before import:

```
svn mkdir https://svn.sources.XXXXXXXX.at/Mactest -F svn-commit.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

We got exactly the same error when we had a version 1.6 server (CentOS 6), but 1.8 clients (Windows). Fortunately, we were able to upgrade the server to 1.8. After that the problem disappeared.